# Android phone not recognized when connected to Ubuntu, by 'adb devices'

Tags: adb

Upgraded my HTC Slide to Froyo. Connecting Ubuntu 10.10 via USB.

As per instructions here, http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

```
    $ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
    SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0BB4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
    $ ls -l /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 72 2011-10-23 20:57 /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
    $ adb devices
    List of devices attached 
    ????????????    no permissions
```

Comment: did you execute `chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` ?

Comment: Check you have usb debugging enabled and plug out and in again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had this very issue earlier tonight myself.

The 51-android.rules needs to be world read-execute, and it's probably best to run `service udev restart` (or reboot) after changing this, then re-plug your device.

If it still doesn't work, double-check the vendor ID you've supplied; with your Android device connected, run `lsusb`. HTC also use the vendor ID `18d1` on newer devices.

Comment: Or `/etc/init.d/udev restart`

Comment: My HTC device is at least an year old. Yet, I had to use 18d1. The android website says 0bb4. Dont know why 0bb4 doesnt work any more. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue myself when rooting my kindle fire and I did:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules     
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="1949", MODE="0666"
```

Then in my `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` file I added

```
0x1949
```

Where 1949 is the vendor id for the kindle I believe.

And after restarting the box, `adb devices` shows my kindle. 
Or instead of restarting `udevadm control --reload-rules` and `adb kill-server && adb start-server` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to work with devices on a very infrequent basis, you can restart the adb server daemon as root.

`./adb kill-server`

`sudo ./adb devices`

Please note that it's *not* a good idea to make the daemon run as root - any security issues in the daemon will now have root access and ANY user on your system who can run adb (not just your user account) can access the devices - as you're basically ignoring all permission settings in 51-android.rules.

As of note, you do not need to be root to shut down the server - just use `./adb kill-server` again.